# waiting threads in a syncronized block

Tags: java, multithreading

if i have these functions

```
public void methodA(){
          synchronized (ObjectAlwaysDifferent) {
          ....
          }
    }
public void methodB(){

}
```

And threads that can enter inside the `synchronized` block so,

```
Thread1 enter with Object1
Thread2 enter with Object2
```

and another thread

```
Thread3  want to enter with Object1
```

if thread loop is:

```
public void run(){
  while(true){
     methodA();
     methodB();
  }
}
```

*`thread3` will wait inside the `methodA`,until the `lock` of object1 will released?
 or it ' s able to go to execute the `methoB` if it's monitor object is locked by another `thread`?*

***it is possible to rewrite the methodA() using Lock and condition of (concurrent API)?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Thread3 would wait until lock gets released.

You are looking for **tryLock()** from **Lock** interface

From [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#tryLock()) :

```
boolean tryLock()
Acquires the lock only if it is free at the time of invocation.
Acquires the lock if it is available and returns immediately with the value true. If the lock is not available then this method will return immediately with the value false.

A typical usage idiom for this method would be:

      Lock lock = ...;
      if (lock.tryLock()) {
          try {
              // manipulate protected state
          } finally {
              lock.unlock();
          }
      } else {
          // perform alternative actions
      }

This usage ensures that the lock is unlocked if it was acquired, and doesn't try to unlock if the lock was not acquired.
Returns:
true if the lock was acquired and false otherwise
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, so it remains inside the methodA() and it will not execute methoB() if it dont consume methodA.

Comment: It will wait until the lock get's released, yes. Also keep in mind that if you have a lot of threads, order is not guaranteed when releasing the locks (a random thread will own the lock, not by order of request of the lock). If this is important to you, consider using an ReentrantLock instead.